# How to split a path platform independent?

Tags: java, regex, file, cross-platform

I'm using the following code to get an array with all sub directories from a given path.

```
String[] subDirs = path.split(File.separator);
```

I need the array to check if certain folders are at the right place in this path.
This looked like a good solution until findBugs complains that File.separator is used as a regular expression. It seems that passing the windows file separator to a function that is building a regex from it is a bad idea because the backslash being an escape character.

How can I split the path in a cross platform way without using File.separator? 
Or is code like this okay?

```
String[] subDirs = path.split("/");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `path.getParentFile()` repeatedly to get all components of a path.

<strike>Discouraged way would be to `path.replaceAll("\\", "/").split("/")`.</strike>

Comment: +1 there are hacky ways to do it and write ways to do it. this is the right way and will save you much pain compared to splitting with '/', '\', <inset character for OS you totally forgot about here>

Comment: Yes, I striked the discouraged way. Sorry.

Answer (score 45):

#### Literalizing pattern strings

Whenever you need to literalize an arbitrary`String` to be used as a regex pattern, use [`Pattern.quote`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

From the API:

> `public static String quote(String s)`
>
> Returns a literal pattern `String` for the specified `String`. This method produces a `String` that can be used to create a `Pattern` that would match the string `s` as if it were a literal pattern.
>   Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.
>
> **Parameters:** `s` - The string to be literalized
>   **Returns:** A literal string replacement

This means that you can do the following:

```
String[] subDirs = path.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator));
```

---

#### Literalizing replacement strings

If you need to literalize an arbitrary replacement `String`, use [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29).

From the API:

> `public static String quoteReplacement(String s)`
>
> Returns a literal replacement `String` for the specified `String`. This method produces a `String` that will work as a literal replacement `s` in the `appendReplacement` method of the `Matcher` class. The `String` produced will match the sequence of characters in `s` treated as a literal sequence. Slashes (`'\'`) and dollar signs (`'$'`) will be given no special meaning.
>
> **Parameters:** `s` - The string to be literalized
>   **Returns:** A literal string replacement

This quoted replacement `String` is also useful in `String.replaceFirst` and `String.replaceAll`:

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Use `Matcher.quoteReplacement` to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

---

#### Examples

```
    System.out.println(
        "O.M.G.".replaceAll(".", "!")
    ); // prints "!!!!!!"

    System.out.println(
        "O.M.G.".replaceAll(Pattern.quote("."), "!")
    ); // prints "O!M!G!"

    System.out.println(
        "Microsoft software".replaceAll("so", "$0")
    ); // prints "Microsoft software"

    System.out.println(
        "Microsoft software".replaceAll("so", Matcher.quoteReplacement("$0"))
    ); // prints "Micro$0ft $0ftware"
```

Answer (score 4):

Create an empty list and use forEach to iterate over the path elements inserting each one into the list for later use:

```
List<String> pathElements = new ArrayList<>();
Paths.get("/foo/bar/blah/baz").forEach(p -> pathElements.add(p.toString()))
```

Also, if you need a specific path element use:

```
<pathObject>.getName(<intIndex>).toString()
```

where `<pathObject>` is returned by a call to `Paths.get()`, and if you need multiple parts of the path returned in a string use:

```
<pathObject>.subPath(<intStart>, <intEnd>).toString()
```

You can get the total number of path elements (for use in `<intEnd>`) with:

```
<pathObject>.getNameCount()
```

There are other useful methods at the Java [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) doc pages.

Comment: Please add explanation why your code works and how does it solve the issues in the question

Comment: If it gives a solution, please provide an explanation or the answer will be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

[java.nio.file.Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) implements `Iterable<Path>`, so you can do:

```
public static void showElements(Path p) {
    List<String> nameElements = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Path nameElement: p)
        nameElements.add(nameElement.toFile().getName());
    System.out.printf("For this file: [%s], the following elements were found: [%s]\n"
                      , p.toAbsolutePath()
                      , Joiner.on(", ").join(nameElements));
}
```

Methods [getNameCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getNameCount()) and [getName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getName(int)) can be used for a similar purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Path interface:

```
Path p = Paths.get(pathStr);
for (int i = 0; i < p.getNameCount(); i++) {
    String name = p.getName(i).toString();
    //do what you need with name;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

What about

```
String[] subDirs = path.split(File.separator.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\"));
```

Comment: Question says cross platform, yours only works for windows.