# Groovy split using file.seperator

Tags: groovy, split

I'm getting an error as follows

```
Groovy script throws an exception of type class 
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException with message = 
Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^
```

from the Split statement as follows:

```
 String strClassPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
 String[] path = strClassPath.split(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
```

How should I make this work correctly for both UNIX and Windows systems (that's why I'm using "file.separator")

Many thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a path platform independent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099859/how-to-split-a-path-platform-independent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This calls java's `split(String regexp)`.  So your input must be a regexp (or must be quoted):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def cp = {path, sep ->
    path.split(Pattern.quote(sep)) 
}

assert cp('C:\\window\\something\\groovy.jar', '\\') == ['C:', 'window', 'something', 'groovy.jar']
assert cp('/usr/local/share/groovy.jar', '/') == ['', 'usr', 'local', 'share', 'groovy.jar']
```

So much for the regexp/split.  If you are after the path, you might be better off using `Path`. e.g.

```
assert new File('/usr/local/share/groovy.jar').toPath().collect()*.toString() == ['usr', 'local', 'share', 'groovy.jar']
```