# What is causing the unexpected internal error when splitting a file path?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am trying to split a file path in JMeter(3.2) using groovy and getting the below error.

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index
1
\
^
```

I was able to solve the problem using the solution mentioned in [Groovy split using file.seperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257759/groovy-split-using-file-seperator) but i want to know why i was getting the error.

This is what my code looked like

```
    \\executePath variable has C:\temp\somepath\anotherfolder\
    def aa = vars.get("executePath").split("\\\\");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that error should only appear when you split on "\\", likely because that gets read as the escape character for the regex and nothing gets escaped. Are you sure you're not using

```
split("\\")
```

When I try the following, I get the correct output

```
def bb = 'C:\\temp\\somepath\\anotherfolder\\'
def aa = bb.split('\\\\')
println aa
Output [C:, temp, somepath, anotherfolder]
```

What are you trying to accomplish by splitting the file path that couldn't be done with java's Path interface?

Comment: my path didn't have double backslashes so this didn't work for me.

Comment: The String representation should have \\ since you have to escape the backslash. def bb = 'C:\temp\somepath\anotherfolder\' would cause errors

Comment: I am getting the path from `${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}` and when i log.info the variable that holds this i get a path without double backslashes.

Comment: Sure, that's because you're log is printing the represented value and not the actual values of the string. To see what values are stored, you can try log.info groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()));    
Keep in mind that the backslash is an escape character for the regex and the string, which is why you need 4 backslashes

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [Pattern.quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) to escape any special characters
2. Use [File.separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) instead of hard-coded backslash, this way your test will be platform-independent.

Example Groovy code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

def aa = vars.get('executePath').split(Pattern.quote(File.separator))

aa.each {
    log.info ("${it}")
}
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy split file path]

I would also recommend seeing [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for some more Groovy hints with regards to scripting in JMeter.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that the next time but it still doesn't answer the why of the error.