# My jar runs on Ubuntu but not Windows

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm, cross-platform

I have created a Java project in NetBeans and the automatically built distribution file (.jar) runs absolutely fine on my Ubuntu 15.04 AMD64 machine.

I wanted to make sure it runs on windows before I distribute it, but having tested on a windows 7 32 bit machine I found it doesn't work. Below is a screen shot of the error message.

[image: The error shown on windows terminal]

I can guess at some issues - in that it talks about a .regex error. I don't really use regex in my code but use String.split which I think calls on the regex package - that is in my constructor for the FileHandler class. So it looks like that is an issue.

You can see the full code here on GitHub :

https://github.com/samredway/PwStore/tree/master/src/com/redway_soft/pwstore

The Java version on the target machine is: 1.8.0_45
As is the same on my build machine.

Any help much much appreciated.

EDIT the specific section causing the problem seems to be the constructor for my FileHandler class. Which looks like this:

```
public FileHandler() {       

    String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
            .getLocation().toString().substring(5);

    String[] arry_path = path.split(File.separator);

    path = "";
    for (int i = 0, j = arry_path.length - 1; i < j; i++) {
        path += arry_path[i] + File.separator;
    }

    PASSWORDS = path + "data" + File.separator + "passwords.sec";

}
```

Comment: Hint for your next question: as the stacktrace gives information on the exact error location, at least paste a number of lines related to that line into the question.  First of all you force people to head over to an external site, and on the next commit you will do the line numbers referred to in the stacktrace become essentially invalid, strongly reducing the usefulness of your question.

Comment: I updated the question to include the relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: super, thanks!  It makes the question a whole lot more interesting for posterity!

Comment: Please copy/paste the text (which is not only less bytes, but search engine friendly) rather than embed an image of the text.  To copy text from the Windows CLI, right click in the window, choose copy, drag across the text to be copied, then press the enter key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line seems to be your problem.

```
String[] arry_path = path.split(File.separator);
```

The file separator on Windows is different from that on a Unix operating system like Ubuntu.

The file separator used in Windows is `\` which is a special character in regex and needs to be escaped for the regex to compile.

As pointed out by [nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo)  below, this can easily be remedied by changing the line into:

```
String[] arry_path = path.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator));
```

Comment: So how should I rewrite this to make it properly cross platform please?

Comment: ```String[] arry_path = path.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator))``` as nneonneo wrote below

Comment: I accepted your answer as you posted first but you should paste the comment above into the answer so it is more visible and people can see it straight away.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing

```
path.split(File.separator)
```

and on Windows the separator is `\` which is not a valid regex.

Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736278/1204143, try using

```
path.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator))
```

instead.